# How to lower child domain and forest functional level?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, subdomain

I [added a child domain (ab.xyz.com) to an existing forest (xyz.com)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574105.aspx) in Active Directory Domain Services. Both domain controllers are running Windows Server 2012 R2.

I want to lower the child domain and forest functional level so that I can join another DC to the child domain which is running Windows Server 2008 R2. I followed [these steps](http://blogs.technet.com/b/aman/archive/2012/12/29/step-by-step-guide-to-lower-active-directory-functional-level.aspx) to lower the child domain and forest functional level. However, it doesn't work.

I entered

```
Set-ADForestMode -Identity “ab.xyz.com” -ForestMode Windows2008Forest
Set-ADDomainMode -Identity “ab.xyz.com” -DomainMode Windows2008Domain
```

But I got an error

> Insufficient access right to perform this operation

When I am logging in as the administrator account of the child domain.

Can anyone give me some idea on how to lower the domain and forest functional level of my child domain?

Comment: I suspect you need to be using an account with enterprise admin rights to the forest as well as domain admin rights to the target domain.

Comment: I logged in with an enterprise admin account to the Child domain controller. However, I feel the enterprise admin account of the parent domain has limited access in the Child DC. For example, not able to click the "Start" button.

Comment: Limited access is correct (domain admins for parent domains are not automatically granted admin rights on child domains); but not even being able to click Start is quite strange. Maybe there's some bizarre GPO in place.

Comment: Are you running it from the server that has the PDC emulator role on it?

Comment: Andre, I am running it on PDC emulator role server of my child domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need enterprise admin rights in order to change the forest functional level.

Domain admin rights *should* be enough to change the functional level of a single domain, but it looks like this is not the case when lowering it, although I wasn't able to find any documentation for this.

Anyway, since you need to change both the forest and the domain level, just perform these operations using an enterprise admin account and they will work.

Also, beware of User Account Control; make sure to run your commands from an elevated PowerShell prompt.

Comment: When I logged in to the Child domain DC with enterprise admin, XYZ\administrator, I found the "Start" button has been disabled. I tried to run the commands, Set-ADForestMode and –ForestMode and got the error: Set-ADForestMode : A referral was returned from the server
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ADForestMode –Identity “ab.xyz.com” –ForestMode Windows2008R2Forest
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (ab.xyz.com:ADForest) [Set-ADForestMode], ADReferralExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8235,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADForestMode

Comment: Try running it on a DC for the forest root domain. Or use the `-server` parameter to tell it which DC to use for the operation.

Comment: I tried to run it on a DC for the forest root domain and use -server parameter in the command. I got the same error message shown in my previous message.

Comment: "A referral was returned" means you are talking to the wrong DC, which is replying something like "I can't do this, you need to contact another DC". Try running the command on a DC for the forest root domain, without using the `-server` parameter. If this still fails, then there probably are some issues in your AD topology.

Comment: I tried to run the command w/ and w/o the -Server parameter. Both commands don't work. May I know if the way I am adding a child domain is wrong ? The steps I applied are attached on my question.

Comment: If you were doing something wrong while adding the child domain, you would have gotten an error then; if the domain has been added correctly, then there probably was nothing wrong there.

Comment: I received no error while adding a child domain. Is there any possible issue which stop me from lowering the child domain DFL and FFL ? This is killing me. I couldn't find useful solution on the net either.

Answer (score 0):

You definitly need enterprise admin rights to lower the forest functional level and DA to change a single domain.  Note that only raising the DFL and FFL is supported as far as I can tell:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617230.aspx

Comment: You can lower it: http://blogs.technet.com/b/aman/archive/2012/12/29/step-by-step-guide-to-lower-active-directory-functional-level.aspx

Comment: A blog post telling you what can be done is a far cry from being supported.  The link above seems pretty definitive to me.

Comment: The example in your link is from 2012 to 2000. This is not supported. You can, however, freely move between 2008, 2012 R2 and everything in between, assuming no capabilities of the higher level are enabled, such as Kerberos Armoring. It is entirely supported.

Comment: This is simply incorrect - it has 200 as an example only the documentation for set-addomainmode says specifically "You can change the domain mode to a mode with higher functionality only. "  While the doc has not been updated for type 6 (2012r2) I have no doubt that they will not remove the "raise only" caveat that has been in place since 2003.

Comment: I don't know how else to put it other than you're simply wrong. If you want a TechNet article as proof, here's one: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I don't see anywhere there showing that it's supported.  (and the technet article you posted points directly at set-addomainmode for more details.  The reason this works at all (and won't work pre 2003) is that it's changing the ms-ds behavior property- it doesn't revert the changes (which are only supported when the FFL/DFL matches).  You can test this yourself by creating a policy silo object and watch it not change at all.  I agree it's unclear and needs to be fixed.

Comment: How can you say it's not supported? There are two entire tables that outline "rollback options."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32329/discussion-between-jim-b-and-mdmarra).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you will get "Set-ADForestMode : A referral was returned from the server" when you target any DC other than the Schema Master. Where "Set-ADDomainMode" needs to target the PDC Emulator, so "Set-ADForestMode" needs to target the Schema Master. In a 'child' domain you have no Schema Master as this is in the Forest root domain, so you would need to reduce the FFL (as an Enterprise Admin) targeting the SM at the forest root, then the DFL as an Enterprise Admin on the PDC of the child domain.